# Can't run build on TFS, autorization error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration

I have following situation - I have build service that serves project collection on

```
http://localhost:7575/tfs/defaultcollection
```

Build service and TFS running on the same virtual machine.

But when I run build from VS build failed with exception:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \HelloWorld\test___3: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean     waitCompletionNotification)

at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection   projectCollection, String itemPath)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
at            Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(Workflow    ManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error,  Boolean& syncLockTaken)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://HelloWorld.com:7575. (type    VssUnauthorizedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.  <DownloadFileFromTfsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Correct me if I wrong - when build started, he requested TFS build service, service calls TFS DefaultCollection address, invokes active controller with free agent, and build starts.

In my case build service calls wrong DefaultCollection address -   `http://HelloWorld.com:7575` instead `http://localhost:7575/tfs`, and for these cause authentication failed.

So, am I rigth in my suggestions, and what I can do to fix it?

I've added following code in TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config file

`<system.diagnostics>
        <switches>
            <add name="BuildServiceTraceLevel" value="4"/>
        </switches>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
                <add name="myListener" type="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationTextWriterTraceListener,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" initializeData="c:\logs\TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.log" />
         <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>`

and got in log only that:

```
[, PID 13344, TID 15088, 2014/09/18 10:09:07.917] Web method running:     [http://localhost:7575/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/connectionData?    connectOptions=IncludeServices&lastChangeId=-1] (GET)connectionData[connectionData]
[, PID 13344, TID 10064, 2014/09/18 10:09:08.100] Web method response: [http://localhost:7575/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=IncludeServices&lastChangeId=-1] (GET)connectionData[connectionData] 181 ms
```

Comment: can you add the build log? please

Comment: @JustTFS: Yes, sure, I've updated my main post with config info.

Comment: can you have a look in your project and see what port the hello web app is set to run on?

Comment: @JustTFS execuse me, I'm not clearly understand, what you mean, what means port is set to run on?

Comment: sorry, in the web application, right click > properties. then the web tab. I'm trying to establish if you are building to the same port as the TFS service. in the TFS admin console what have you got set as the URL value?

Comment: @JustTFS May be I'm explained my problem not the best way(  I have no web app here. On the `http://HelloWorld:7575/tfs` located my TFS  projects collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61490/discussion-between-just-tfs-and-brewerof).

Comment: Same problem here, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you run VS as administrator.